# Python pygal code - World map

Tags: python, ipython, spyder, pygal, world-map

Could you please help me with this code:

```
import pygal
from pygal.maps.world import World
worldmap_chart = pygal.maps.world.World()
worldmap_chart.title = 'Some countries'
worldmap_chart.add('F countries', ['fr', 'fi'])
worldmap_chart.add('M countries', ['ma', 'mc', 'md', 'me', 'mg',
                               'mk', 'ml', 'mm', 'mn', 'mo',
                               'mr', 'mt', 'mu', 'mv', 'mw',
                               'mx', 'my', 'mz'])
worldmap_chart.add('U countries', ['ua', 'ug', 'us', 'uy', 'uz'])
worldmap_chart.render()
```

I use Spyder. Python 3.6
.The problem is that the map does not show up on the IPython console, and also on the second line of the code, I get yellow triangle/note that says: 'pygal.maps.world.World' imported but unused. Maybe this is the reason why the map does not show up.

Otherwise, if it helps, in the IPython console I get only this: runfile('C:/Users/Nikki/.spyder-py3/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Nikki/.spyder-py3')

Could you please help me to fix this.

Thanks,

Nikki

Comment: Is the map supposed to generate some HTML/Javascript code? Because if that's the case, then it won't work in Spyder, only in the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Well the output should look something like this:http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/maps/pygal_maps_world.html        I don't know why it does not display the map. I also try with a more simple code, and there is no import error, but the map just don't appear: import pygal
                      worldmap_chart = pygal.maps.world.World()
                      worldmap_chart.title = 'Some countries'
                      worldmap_chart.render()

Comment: Does it work in the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: When I try in Jupyter I get a bunch of alpha numerical output like this: b'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?>\n<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="chart-f956a514-37d7-4518-992a-7e5e95095928" class="pygal-chart" viewBox="0 0 800 600"><!--Generated with pygal 2.4.0 (lxml) \xc2\xa9Kozea 2012-2016 on 2017-12-28--><!--http://pygal.org--><!--http://github.com/Kozea/pygal--><defs><style type="text/css">#chart-f956a514-37d7-4518-992a-7e5e95095928{-webkit-user-select:none;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;font-family:Consolas,"Liberat...

Comment: That's not numerical output, it's some kind of HTML. So (although failing), it seems `pygal` maps are only supposed to work in the Jupyter notebook, not in Spyder, sorry.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the efforts.

Answer (score 1):

To put this here to help others trying to use `pygal` to create maps.
Yes, following from what @Carolos said, you can also easily export them as html. like this:

```
import pygal
from pygal.maps.world import World
worldmap_chart = World()

worldmap_chart.title = 'Some countries'
worldmap_chart.add('F countries', ['fr', 'fi'])
worldmap_chart.add('M countries', ['ma', 'mc', 'md', 'me', 'mg',
                                   'mk', 'ml', 'mm', 'mn', 'mo',
                                   'mr', 'mt', 'mu', 'mv', 'mw',
                                   'mx', 'my', 'mz'])
worldmap_chart.add('U countries', ['ua', 'ug', 'us', 'uy', 'uz'])
worldmap_chart.render_to_file('mymap.html')
```